# Export solution pool from scripting log to excel Cplex

Tags: cplex

I am writing a consolidation model for my thesis. Through the use of solution pools, I am able to see all feasible, non-optimal solutions. However, I am not really familiar with this command, so I need some help to write these outputs to excel. Here is the relevant part of my code where y is a binary variable that equals 1 if order n is consolidated at terminal j from non-consolidated truck g to consolidated truck h at time t:

```
dvar int+ y[gateway_terminal, truck, cons_truck, time, order] in 0..1; 
{tuple_y} output_y = {<i,g,h,t,n,y[i,g,h,t,n]> | i in gateway_terminal, g in truck, h in cons_truck, t in time, n in order: y[i,g,h,t,n] == 1}; //tuple to show optimal outcome in excel

//ALTERNATIVE FEASIBLE (NON_OPTIMAL) SOLUTIONS
execute 
{
writeln("Total cost equals to ", total_cost, " and the consolidated orders are ", output_y);
}

main { cplex.solnpoolintensity = 4;
thisOplModel.generate();
cplex.solve();
if (cplex.populate()) {
  var nsolns = cplex.solnPoolNsolns;
  
  writeln("Number of solutions found = ", nsolns);
  writeln();
  for (var s=0; s<nsolns; s++) {
    thisOplModel.setPoolSolution(s);
    thisOplModel.postProcess();
  }
 }
}
```

Does someone know how I export this information to excel? Many thanks for your help! Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a .dat file in the flow control and then use this .dat to write into Excel.

Let me use as an example 2 examples in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/

- [Get several solutions](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooseveral.mod)
- [Excel spreadsheets](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooexcel.mod)

  ```
   int nbKids=300;
   float costBus40=500;
   float costBus30=400;

   dvar int+ nbBus40;
   dvar int+ nbBus30;

   minimize
     costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;

   subject to
   {
     40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
   }
   tuple t
   {
    int n40;
    int n30;
   }

   t sol=<nbBus40,nbBus30>;
   execute
   {
    writeln("nbBus40 = ",nbBus40," and nbBus30 = ",nbBus30," and the cost is      ",costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30);
   }

    main {
      var outputfile=new IloOplOutputFile("sols.dat");
      outputfile.writeln("sols={");

    cplex.solnpoolintensity=4;

       thisOplModel.generate();
       cplex.solve();
        if (cplex.populate()) {
           var nsolns = cplex.solnPoolNsolns;


          writeln("Number of solutions found = ",nsolns);
          writeln();
          for (var s=0; s<nsolns; s++) {
           thisOplModel.setPoolSolution(s);
            thisOplModel.postProcess();
           outputfile.writeln(thisOplModel.sol,",");
          }
       }
        outputfile.writeln("};");
        outputfile.close();
   }
  ```

which builds sols.dat

```
sols={
 <6 2>,
 <9 0>,
 <7 1>,
 <8 1>,
 <7 2>,
 <10 0>,
 <9 1>,
 <8 2>,
 <6 3>,
 <5 4>,
 <7 3>,
 <11 0>,
 <9 2>,
 <6 4>,
 <4 5>,
 <5 5>,
 <7 4>,
 <10 1>,
 <3 6>,
 <9 3>,
 <12 0>,
 <8 3>,
 <5 6>,
 <10 2>,
 <9 4>,
 <6 5>,
 <4 6>,
 <4 7>,
 <4 8>,
 <4 9>,
 <4 10>,
 <4 11>,
 <11 1>,
 <11 2>,
 <11 3>,
 <11 4>,
 <11 5>,
 <11 6>,
 <8 0>,
};
```

and then you may use

```
tuple t
    {
      int n40;
      int n30;
    }
    
     {t} sols=...;
```

with that sols.dat to write to Excel those solutions

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much for the explanation! I have successfully created the sols.dat file, but could you please clarify where I need to write the `{t} sols=...;` to write it to excel? In the original .mod file, I get an error that sols is not defined. Do I need to make a new .mod? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Do not hesitate to accept this answer.